# Solving TSP with DEAP - How to freez first and last town?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetic, deap

I have large dataset with flights prices

```
CITY_ORIGIN, CITY_DESTINATION, PRICE
```

I want to solve TSP problem of finding the cheapest trip starting in `CITY_START` ending in `CITY_END` and going, through max `N` cities from `CITIES_THROUGH` array.

I'm trying to solve this task with DEAP python lib using [TSP example](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/tsp.py) code.

How to freeze first and last towns in DEAP TSP example?

f.e.

```
CITY_START = "London"
CITY_END = "Paris"
CITY_THROUGH = ["Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Rome", "Barcelona"]
CITY_MAX = 2
```

So I want to limit algorithm to find the cheapest flight in such subset of possible solutions:

```
London -> [CITY_MAX random cities from CITY_THROUGH] -> Paris
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to map your flight price data to nested dictionaries:

```
flight_price = {"london": {"paris": 100}}
```

Now you just need to adapt the evaluate function:

```
def evalTSP(individual):
    cities = ["london"] + individual + ["paris"]
    price = sum(flight_price[start][end] for start, end in zip(cities, cities[1:]))
    return price,


evalTSP([])
>>> 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on an implementation of a solution for the TSP based on:

```
https://github.com/lmarti/evolutionary-computation-course/blob/master/AEC.03%20-%20Solving%20the%20TSP%20with%20GAs.ipynb
```

So for my implementation I have an initial list of cities, called 'cities', and I represent each individual as a list of indices that correspond to the position of each city in the initial list. That means that for generating new individuals the mechanism is according to the numpy's random.permutation function. But there are two cases, one is when the starting and ending point are not fixed so we declare the mechanisms in the toolbox as follows:

```
toolbox.register("indices", numpy.random.permutation, len(cities))
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.indices)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

But, just in case that the first and last locations of the initial list of 'cities' are fixed then you need to permutate through the rest of the locations except for the first and the last. So you declare the mechanisms like this:

```
permutableList = []
for row in range(1, len(cities)-1):
    permutableList.append(row-1)

toolbox.register("indices", numpy.random.permutation, permutableList)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.indices)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

Then you just need to change the evaluation function to include the first and the last points of the initial list of "cities", as follows:

```
def create_tour(individual):

    listOfLocations = [list(cities)[e+1] for e in individual]
    # Adding first and last points to the tour
    listOfLocations.insert(0, cities[0])
    listOfLocations.append(cities[len(cities)-1])

    return listOfLocations
```

And then you calculate the distance based on the listOfLocations list.